# How to query a Django model defining a IP range with two int fields (IP, mask)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have:

```
class Range(models.Model):
    ip = models.IntegerField() # as produced by socket.inet_aton + struct.unpack
    mask = models.IntegerField()
```

Given a certain IP, how can I get all the ranges that match this specific IP using the Django models?

If I were using raw SQL, I would use the database's bitwise operators, but the Django ORM doesn't support those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QuerySet API in Django 1.0 now includes the 'extra' method, described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) in the Django docs. The extra method allows you to pass custom WHERE clauses to your QuerySet, which should allow you to use the bitwise comparison you need.

Answer (score 2):

To do faster query fitting the range you'd better store lower and upper IP of range as integer. Then selection of needed objects should be as simple as `Range.objects.filter(ip_low__le=ip, ip_up__ge=ip)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using python's iptools :

http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/